# Eloquent nested relationship

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

i have a question to my db query.

My DB tables/schema:

- customers_users (customer_id, user_id) relationship table
- projects (project_id, customer_id, [.......]) belongs to customers

i try to get all Projects where a user has access through customers to, with the following query:

```
//call
User::find(Auth::id())->first()->projects();

//User.model
public function projects() {
    return User::with('customers.projects')->get();
}
```

It works. But now i have User data, Customer data and Project Data in the result array. I want only the Projects. Is there an other way?

Comment: Q:1 what laravel version are you using? Q:2 so you only want to retrieve the Projects from all customers for a specific user?

Comment: Hello, Q:2: yes! exactly.  Q:1: where i can check the version?

Answer (score 0):

```php
$user = auth()->user()->load('customers.projects');

$projects = $user->customers->pluck('projects')->collapse()->unique();
```

Comment: I believe `hasManyThrough` only works when the intermediate relationship is a one-to-one or one-to-many. From the table description, it looks like the user relationship to customers is many-to-many, so a `hasManyThrough` relationship won't work.

Comment: @freeza - The code in my answer works for your relationships.

Comment: in my laravel version auth is undefined. i Tryed anstead User::find(Auth::id())->with('customers.projects') but it doesnt work.

Comment: @freeza - Use `Auth::user()->load('customers.projects')`. Seem you're using an older version of Laravel.

Comment: @JosephSilber At first, thanks for your help! The Log says no pluck is not defined.

$user = Auth::user()->load('customers.projects');

$projects = $user->customers->pluck('projects')->collapse()->unique();

Comment: Use this: `collect($user->customers->lists('projects'))->collapse()`. It would really help if you would just tell us which version of Laravel you're using. Or even better, upgrade!